# Xp to Ubuntu issues

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have an XP computer, and I am trying to setup a dual boot configuration with Ubuntu. I copied the wubi.exe to a flashdrive and copied it into a separate partition. It took several hours to install, but everything seemed to be fine.

However, I rebooted and nothing happened. As suggested on the website, I pressed f12 - but I didn't understand anything.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: did you read any of these documentations [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Windows) or [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) and all kinds of [installing Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) also take a look at [Wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Dual-Boot-Windows-XP-and-Ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

read this page how to install ubuntu using wubi

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide

if u want to install ubuntu to other partition other than ur ' C drive' then you should select that other drive letter at installation drive option after u run wubi(u told u copied wubi to separate partition thats not needed)

if u have ubuntu iso file and want to install ubuntu with wubi offline u can do it by placing wubi and iso file in a single folder with no other files and run wubi (disconnect ur network before)